# Spring WS "The security token could not be authenticated or authorized"

Tags: spring-security, soapui, spring-ws, soap-client

I'm creating a java client consumer for a web service using SpringWS-Security.

**My Request SOAP (That I use in SOAP UI)**

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
         xmlns:sch="http://myws.mycompany.com/myws/schema"> 

    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" 
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">

            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/utility">
                    <wsse:Username>myUsernameString</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">123</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        </soapenv:Header>

    <soapenv:Body>
        <sch:GetUserDetails idSender="5"/>
    </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**My servlet.xml in the WS.**

```
<bean name="endpointMapping"
  class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping">

  <property name="interceptors">
   <list>
    <ref local="wsSecurityInterceptor" />
   </list>
 </property>


    <bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor"
                        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken" />
        <property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="springSecurityCallbackHandler" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="springSecurityCallbackHandler"
                        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationProvider" class="ws.security.CustomAuthenticationProviderImpl">
            <property name="userCommonService" ref="userCommonService" />
        <security:custom-authentication-provider/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" />.
```

**In my Java Client - applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean name="webserviceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <property name="defaultUri" value="http:/localhost:8080/myws-ws/" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="unmarshaller" />
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref local="wsSecurityInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller"
        contextPath="org.example.bean.schema" />
    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="unmarshaller"
        contextPath="org.example.org.bean.schema" />

    <bean id="client" class="example.client.impl.EfactClientImpl">
        <property name="webServiceTemplate" ref="webserviceTemplate" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken"/>
    </bean>
```

When I use SOAP UI to consume the service everything is going fine, I think I need a little help at the Java Client and its context because when I run it I got this error:

```
The security token could not be authenticated or authorized; nested exception is: 
    javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException; nested exception is org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized; nested exception is: 
    javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException
```

When I debug my app I can notice that this element is crashing:

```
GetUserRequest request = new GetUserRequest();
        request.setIdentifier(user.getIdentifier());
        request.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        GetUserResponse response = new GetUserResponse();
/* Crashing here. */
response = (GetUserResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request);
```

FYI: I always see this list of users in SpringWS with security, but what if I have a lot of users trying to access.

**WS - [servlet-name]-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="callbackHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
    <property name="users">
      <props>
        <prop key="Bert">Ernie</prop>
        <prop key="Mickey">Mouse</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

How can I resolve this UnsupportedCallbackException Exception?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when I upgraded from cfx 2.2.X to 2.7.X. Due to feature upgrades, the server side code was not able to read the password as a result the password was received as null by the server. Make sure the server received the correct username and password, which would fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify SecurementUsername and SecurementPassword at call time. This is a programmatically example:

```
WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(uri);

Wss4jSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
interceptor.setSecurementActions(securementActions);
interceptor.setSecurementMustUnderstand(true);
interceptor.setSecurementUsername(usuario);
interceptor.setSecurementPassword(contrasena);

webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[] {interceptor});
```